# What is "Role Conversion" actually do on SharePoint 2016 on-premise?

Tags: distributedcache, minrole

We have a SP2016 (16.0.4327.1000 build, Release candidate) installed. I checked there is no Distrubuted Cache service setup. So I set it up on 2 WFE server. After that I change the role of WFE servers to "Custom". I found nothing have changed but I am not sure. All services on WFE have same status before conversion.

May I know what is "Role conversion" actually perform beside change the naming?

P.S. by some project restriction I cannot patch the farm at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a new farm, `Custom` servers [will get the following services by default](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/description-of-minrole-and-associated-services-in-sharepoint-server-2016#minrole-and-associated-services-for-each-server-role):

- Distributed Cache
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Administration
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application

All other services can and must be manually configured by your specific needs.

MinRole will no longer take care of the started services if you switch an existing system to `custom`. **All existing services will keep their state!** You an manage them via `Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage Services on Server`

Comment: What do you mean by "get the services"?  If Distributed cache is not ready,  by change to custom,  dc will be started?

Comment: Also what is "administration" service?  Is it equal to "central administration"?

Comment: Answer to your first comment: Only a new farm will get DistributedCache by default if Custom is selected. Switching to custom will not change any existing Settings. Second comment: SharePoint Administration is not CentralAdmin. Read here fore more details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2012/01/08/the-sharepoint-administration-service-and-spadministrationservicejobdefinition/